# Looking for suggestions on how to compare multiple arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, compare, dynamic-arrays

I need to iterate through n number of arrays with n number of items ,find the matches in each array, create a new array with those items, if there are no item matches for any of the arrays, that would be undefined, for each array that doesn't match, in the new array.

I can do this with 2 arrays but looking for suggestions on how to do it for any number. I'm not necessary looking for you to code it, just some suggestions on how to tackle the problem

```
const one = [[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7,8], [3,4,5,9,10]]
```

The results should be this

```
[[1,undefined,undefined], [2,undefined,undefined], [3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5], [undefined,6,undefined], [undefined, 7,undefined], [undefined, 8, undefined],[undefined,undefined,9], [undefined,undefined,10]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make liberal use of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)s. First, convert each inner list to a set so that you can check if a number is in it fast. Next, you can create a set of all numbers in all lists and, for each number, get your desired list based on whether or not it is contained in each "inner-list set" created earlier:

```js
const one = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [3, 4, 5, 9, 10]
];

const sets = one.map(arr => new Set(arr));
const allNumbers = new Set(one.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.push(...curr);
  return acc;
}, []));

const result = [...allNumbers].map(n => sets.map(s => s.has(n) ? n : undefined));
console.log(result);
```

The trade-off is that the list of sets takes up extra memory (as much as the original 2-d array itself). If that's unacceptable, you can skip it and do a linear time check with `includes` on each inner list in the original array.

Comment: Thank you so much, let me see If I understand. I get what sets is, allNumbers is where I'm a little confused, but its creating a new set from one, reducing it into an array of all values with no repeats?  the result is taking the allNumbers array and iterating through sets to see if the value is there or not.

Comment: @OneFootN Correct. `allNumbers` is a set of all the numbers in all the inner lists but there are no duplicates in it (since a set does not allow duplicates). You're also correct about `result`. You can check out the `Array.map` documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map